# Adding live search in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a possibility to use live autocomplete google search in your own extension? So that user given an input changing that triggers google search with results via JSON or any other convenient format.

[image: live search in google chrome]

I suppose that may be hijacked using AJAX calls to `google.com/?q=` with further parsing the HTML results, but that seems not very clear technique.

I've also checked the [Google chrome API index](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) but didn't find relevant items.

Answer (score -2):

This is not in the official documentation, but digging in other extensions code, showed that this can be achieved via using [JSONP requests](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to `https://suggestqueries.google.com/` url.

Below is the sample code using [jQueryUI autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) width further redirect to Google search results:

```
$("#googleSearch").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data[2].splice(0, 15));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var value = ui.item.label;

            if (ui.item.label.indexOf("http://") === -1 && ui.item.label.indexOf("https://") === -1) {
                value = "http://google.com/search?q=" + value
            }

            document.location = value;
        }
    });
```

If using this approach, the following CSP must be in `manifest.json`:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/ https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/ https://*.googleapis.com/ https://www.google.com/; object-src 'self'",
```

Comment: Hey, man, why giving a -1 without explaining ? I asked a question I didn't know the answer to, 3 day later I've figured it out myself and shared the subject here.

Comment: nowhere in the tags it says about jQuery, you basically adding additional depedency and some people was looking for lightweight solution.

Comment: @Fedcomp toipic is about functionality - **live google seach in the ext**, not the implementation. I used jQuery, since it was fine for that specific project. in this answer I am just sharing my solution. those who need can just rewrite it in vanilla js, right?

Comment: well, when people search for jquery solution they add it to the tags. Not to say jqueryui (just realized) is another huge depedency. No, thoose who need it in native solution will need native solution. jQuery is too specific to "just" rewrite it to javascript.

Comment: @Fedcomp please take a look at the question again - it's my question, in case you've missed it. I was not searching for a jQuery solution, I was searching for ANY solution. If you can't take a look at the jQueryUI code and write your own implementation in vanilla JS, the way you need it - then you should probably go learn a bit of JS instead of giving negative marks to topics you don't clearly understand.